# Deleting a question showed one of the answer as deleted by the owner

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

I have deleted a [question already closed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198/in-path-auto-what-are-the-differences-between-title-title-raw) (the link is for 10k users on *Drupal Answers*), and one of the answer is shown as deleted by the owner, which is not what happened, as I deleted the question, and (indirectly) all the answers.

[image: screenshot]

There was also a pending undelete vote it was not present before I deleted the question; when I voted to undelete it the answer was effectively undeleted. (The answer is now shown as deleted, for those who can see the question I am referring.) Still, I don't understand how there could be an undelete vote, when the answer was not deleted, before I deleted the question.

When I deleted the question, Dave Reid was reported to be seen 18 hours before I deleted it. He could have not deleted his own answer in the same moment I was deleting the question.

#### Update

Looking at [the revision page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/202/revisions) (the link is for 10k users on *Drupal Answers*), I notice the following.

[image: screenshot]

What happened is that effectively the author of the answer deleted the answer, but then undeleted it. When I deleted the question, the system remembered the undelete vote casted from the author, but it didn't remember that vote already had effect; in fact, when I undeleted the answer, the answer is said to be undeleted from the author, and from me (third entry in the screenshot), when it was just me to undelete it because the user logged in 18 hours before I deleted the question.

Comment: What about the answer revisions page? Do you see anything suspicious there?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd I added the screenshot of the revision page; it is something interesting.

Comment: +1, I actually have a post that says "deleted by owner" when I did no such thing. And it got an undelete vote *after it was migrated*. [Still pending](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31476/how-can-i-clear-the-cache-for-specific-flash-games-in-chrome?noredirect=1), actually.

Comment: Looks like the bug here is the answer getting *undeleted then deleted again* when you delete the parent question. We need Nick here! :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd It seems more that the system remembers the undelete vote casted from the author, but it doesn't remember the answer was already undeleted. I guess it sees an undelete vote as last event, and it shows it.